# How to call GRPC Server in NGINX config

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, grpc, kestrel-http-server

How to call GRPC Server which is located in docker container on Swarm cluster from NGINX reverse proxy?

*GRPC Server* in container/service called **webui** with kestrel development certificate installed

*NGINX Proxy* which is located outside the stack and routes access to Swarm stacks

*GRPC Client* is located on a separate virtual machine on another network, the browser page at https://demo.myorg.com is available

part nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name demo.myorg.com;
    ...
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://namestack_webui;
}
```

GRPC Client appsetting.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "Data Source=Server_name;Initial Catalog=DB;User Id=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
  ...
  "GRPCServerUri": "https://demo.myorg.com/",
  ...
      }
  }
```

Problem when connecting GRPC Client to Server, i get error

```
END] GetOpcDaServerSettingsQuery. Time spent: 7,7166ms
fail: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[6]
      Error starting gRPC call.
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
       ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090367): No common application protocol exists between the client and the server. Application protocol negotiation failed..
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Tried to write and specify a kestrel development certificate (for *GRPC Client*) that is loaded into the Swarm stack (**namestack**) through which the other containers in the stack are authenticated, the error is the same.

I understand that it is necessary to specify in *appsetting.json* the *GRPC Server* container address (**https://namestack_webui**), but it is behind NGINX, and I can only specify the GRPC host address (**https://demo.myorg.com**), tell me what is wrong?

The perfect solution for such a case was not found online.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out and found a solution to my question, and I publish it for discussion.
If there are no comments against, then mark it as correct, at least it works for me and will work for YOU.

1. to proxy grpc connections through `NGINX` in the configuration, the `location` section must specify something similar to the url `/PackageName.ServiceName/MethodName` (This is indicated here by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-8.0)
   This URL can be checked with the developer or in the logs when grpc client connects
2. Should be used to proxy directive `grpc_pass grpcs://namecontainer`;
3. Should use `http2` protocol.

So the correct configuration file for nginx in my case should look like this

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl **http2**;
    server_name demo.myorg.com;

    ssl_certificate     ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=604800';
    underscores_in_headers on;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
            
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://name_container;

        # Configuration for WebSockets
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_cache off;
        # WebSockets were implemented after http/1.0
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # Configuration for ServerSentEvents
        proxy_buffering off;
        # Configuration for LongPolling or if your KeepAliveInterval is longer than 60 seconds
        proxy_read_timeout 100s;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-URL-SCHEME https;
    }
    location /App.Name.Api.Contract.ApiService/UpdateOpcDaTags {
        grpc_pass grpcs://name_container;
    }
}
```